# Eclipse STS Gradle Error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have setup a spring boot gradle project in STS. It was working fine till yesterday without any issues.

Today all of a sudden, when I try to run the app as Spring boot, I am getting below error.

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication**

I have checked STS , all the dependent jars are available in the workspace under **'Project and External Dependencies'** .

Can you please guide me in resolving the error

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade STS? Or is it exactly the same STS instance?
If it is exactly the same then it must be something in the Eclipse workspace that might have gotten corrupted. It may be hard and time consuming to understand what exactly went wrong so I'd just do the following:

1. Find the project in the file system and delete all `.project`, `.classpath` files and `.settings` folders for the root Gradle and module projects.
2. Re-import the Gradle project in STS
3. Didn't work? Try opening a brand new workspace and importing the project into it.